# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - change upload directory

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, blueimp

Now, i use Blueimp jQuery File Upload to upload files. I have a question how can i upload in custom folder?. Example: with defaullt Blueimp jQuery File Upload will upload to folder server/php/files and server/php/files/thumbnail. I want to add custom param when upload and it will upload to this folder. Ex: i set it will up load to abc, file upload will upload to folder  server/php/files/abc and server/php/files/thumbnail/abc. I had change data-url in input but it doesnt change
More: in page A i will upload to folder abc,in page B i will upload to folder cde

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/assets/server/php/abc" multiple>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo(document.body);
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                console.log(file);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i just went through the class of the Blueimp jQuery File Uploader. just change the option below to whatever folder you want..

'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',

Comment: Can you post full script? I had pasted it but can't run

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Comment: public function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->response = array();
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
            'input_stream' => 'php://input',
            'user_dirs' => false,
            'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
            'param_name' => 'files',

Answer (score 0):

I did it by passing in options to the UploadHandler contructor:  I changed downloads/server/php/index.php to contain:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
/* the constructor checks method, and performs GET or POST respectively */
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array('upload_dir' => '/var/www/html/downloads/',
                                          'upload_url' => '/downloads/',
                                          ...));
```

(... stands for other options I wanted that you might not care about.)